# Xlib. How to make XGrabButton not consume click?

Tags: linux, x11, window, cpp

First question so please forgive me if I am neglecting a requirement here.

I am attempting to build a window manager for arch linux. Currently, I am adding grab events before mapping a window.

I have the following:

```
XGrabButton(display, Button1, 0, window, false, ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
```

When Button1 is pressed I run this:

```
XRaiseWindow(display, frame);
```

The issue is now I cannot click anything in the window. Only the ButtonPressed callback function is being run. How could I go about (1) making sure the ButtonPress event is also received by the window and (2) only running the XRaiseWindow function if the window is not currently the top window (I assume stack_mode can be used here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved (1) with the following ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288251/capture-button-events-in-xlib-then-passing-the-event-to-the-client)).

Change pointer_mode to GrabModeSync and use

```
XAllowEvents(display, ReplayPointer, event.time);
XSync(display, 0);
```

in the ButtonPressed callback to pass on the click event.

Still looking for (2), although I have found just calling XRaiseWindow without checking if it is necessary is not an issue. To be clear, I have not profiled anything, this is just from my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to build a window manager for arch linux.

That's a pretty big project. In your place I would have looked at the code for an existing window manager first.

> Currently, I am adding grab events before mapping a window.

IIRC, that's not how they do it. Instead they register for events via "redirection", e.g. using `SubstructureRedirectMask`. Have e.g. a look at [this](https://jichu4n.com/posts/how-x-window-managers-work-and-how-to-write-one-part-i/) article series.

> The issue is now I cannot click anything in the window.

Well, yes, you grabbed button events, so now every button event is delivered to the window manager instead of the window (and that's why window managers don't do grabs, usually). If you insist on doing it that way (which I wouldn't), you'd have to decide for each button event if it should be delivered to the window or not, and you'd have to ungrab, produce a second synthetic event, and re-grab for every button event that should be delivered to the window. Not a very doof approach.

> only running the XRaiseWindow function if the window is not currently the top window

So this is about the focus policy ("raise on click")? I am not actually sure how this is implemented, as I wrote above, I'd read code for an existing window manager to find out. Might also be something you can configure in X itself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I found out how to solve my first issue (edited into the question), hopefully I can figure out how to approach the second. Thanks for the link! Hopefully it can provide some insight.

Comment: @Eshy: you should remove the answer from your question, post it as an answer, then accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Gauthier, done. and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

As far as (2), I can share what I've learned in my own WM project so far, although I'm here to try to learn more about some of these techniques myself. Maybe it will help someone else and at minimum I can talk it out a little to myself.

First, you should probably already have some kind of variable in your WM which lets you know without asking X which window is "active". Note that there is a difference between which window is at the top of the stack, and which is focused (receiving keyboard input).

In most desktops we're familiar with they are almost always the same thing but AFAICT X does not really care about that, so it's actually up to you to write something to move the focus around as users expect by sending SetInputFocus requests (XSetInputFocus() in Xlib parlance). XRaiseWindow() on it's own *ONLY* raises the window, it doesn't change the focus at all.

Anyway so you will probably be managing the input focus yourself and so should already have some way internally to know whether a window is the active one or not. You'll need this for one to update the _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW property on the root window that most pagers/taskbars read, and you may also find some edge cases in which you need to re-set the focus yourself, for example if the top-level, focused window is destroyed, then IME X tends to just dump the keyboard focus back to the root window, when what you probably really want in a typical desktop environment is to return the focus to the most recently focused window other than the one that just closed.

In my WM I've been figuring out such find-next-focus scenarios rather easily by just keeping all the clients/containers/decoration windows/whatever-your-particular-WM-calls-them in a linked list, and every time a window is raised/focused, I just move the pointer to it's struct to the end of the clients list which is a pretty cheap operation since it's just a linked list removal+insert. Then if I get a FocusIn for the root window or otherwise determine the WM's assistance is needed to update the focus I can just take the last window still in the list and focus that one.

The other thing I'd mention is that as you've found too, several WMs I've looked at the source to use GrabButton and AllowEvents to detect the "click-to-focus" so that it works if the client area of the window is clicked and not just the titlebars/borders since you don't own the client area. But there's slightly more to the trick here: you should only be grabbing buttons on the windows that are currently unfocused. As soon as the user clicks one and it's raised+focused, we release the grab. I actually do this in a "SetFocus" function used whenever we want to change the focus. This makes sense as it resolves my initial objection upon learning of this technique -- that we don't really want every single mouse click to always get intercepted, bounced to the WM, and then rebroadcast back -- that's terribly inefficient and what if the user is playing a super-intense FPS game or something where the additional lag might not just be inelegant but maybe actually matter? But by adding and removing the grab depending on the window's focus we are only intercepting exactly what we need to to accomplish the desired functionality and most clicks will NOT have that double-bounce going on.

The only parts about this I have not totally figured out is that it seems like if you have an active GrabButton and do NOT call AllowEvents after a click, then X won't send you any further button events. I'm not totally sure why that is yet, but be aware you might encounter that. I just send AllowEvents any time I get a ButtonPress with button 1 (same as my GrabButton condition) on a window that has a grab. But that means that you might want to be able to distinguish between the original event and the replayed one -- otherwise, if they say, click the titlebar(*) rather than the client area, you'll get two ButtonPress events without an intervening ButtonRelease, which may or may not cause subtle problems depending on how you coded your WM.

If there's a need to distinguish them the best way I've found so far is to use the "time" field of the event, which normally constantly increases but will be the same as the grabbed version when the replayed event comes back. So you can record the time field of the last click whose button+state would qualify for the grab in the member variables for that window/client, and e.g. ignore a grab-qualifying ButtonPress with a time field that is equal to the previous qualifying ButtonPress on that window.

(*) I'm grabbing the button on the CONTAINER/DECOR window that I created and reparented the client into, not the original client window, which still captures clicks to the client area since the client has been reparented to be a child of my container. You could probably avoid clicks on the decor part of the window resulting in a double-event by grabbing the client window instead, but I don't like to interact with the client windows more than I need to because since I don't own them, the client can destroy them at any time asynchronous to my code which creates all manner of race conditions that you have to be careful to plan for either by using XGrabServer around critical sections such as the reparenting followed by a query to the server to be sure the window still exists after the GrabServer, or you can do what some minimal WMs such as dwm do and just catch & ignore any errors you might get back from the server because of such a race. But I try to cut down on those kinds of things whenever I can so that's why I'm currently taking the grab on the container.

But then, if you were doing a GrabButton on the client window, maybe you could have just done a SelectInput instead and not needed to grab in the first place.